# JPA One to one update operation

Tags: hibernate

I want to update the employee via Parkingspace, but I do not succeed.  Why can't I update the employee over the parking space?

**Employee Class**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private int salary;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="park_id", unique=true)
private ParkingSpace parkingSpace;
 ...getter/setter

   }
```

**Parkingspace Class**

```
@Entity
public class ParkingSpace {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private int id;
private int parkingLot;
private String location;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parkingSpace",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Employee employee;
....getter/setter
}
```

I want to update the employee via Parkingspace, but I do not succeed.There is no change in the database.

```
...........
entityTransaction.begin();
parkingSpace.setEmployee(employee);
entityTransaction.commit();
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `Session.saveOrUpdate()` before the commit.
Besides, here you seem to change the `employee` relationship :

```
parkingSpace.setEmployee(employee);
```

Note that the `ParkingSpace` entity is not the owner of the relationship between `Employee` and itself as the employee field specifies `mappedBy` in the `OneToOne` annotation :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parkingSpace",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Employee employee;
```

So invoking `parkingSpace.setEmployee(employee);` will be useless.
The `Employee` entity being the owner, you should specify :

```
employee.setParkingSpace(parkingSpace);
```

Comment: There is no change in Employee.
I could not understand . Do not both sides have the right to access and make changes?

Comment: Ah ok. No, both sides don't have the right to reflect change. Only the owner side may. I updated my answer.